# How do I add a list of the opportunities associated with a particular contact to their contact record?

Tags: standard-objects, related-list

I have customer names associated with specific opportunities, and I want to be able to see a list of those opportunities when I look at the contact record. Is this possible?

I tried creating a related list on Opportunity on my Contact page layout, but it does not return any values.

Comment: How are they related? You need to have a relationship between the two (lookup on the opportunity to the contact record) and then you can bring up the related list.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I was missing the relationship. The solution was to assign contact roles on the opportunity. Also had to switch between the two different Opportunity related list options on the contact page layout.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a relationship between the two objects (lookup on the opportunity to the contact) and then you can bring up the related list of opportunities on the contact record. Make sure you select the right related list (if you have multiple relationships).